# Is the credit assignment problem a well-posed one?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, philosophy

Credit assignment is the process of assigning credit (or blame) to a particular move in a sequence of moves (temporal credit assignment) or to a particular node (structural credit assignment) among many nodes, for example, in a network.

My question is somewhat philosophical: Does it even make sense to speak of credit assignment as a problem to be solved?

Take the example of a football (soccer) team. (I read in a paper that robo-soccer teams face a version of the credit assignment problem). However, even in the case of a real-life soccer team composed of humans players, it is virtually impossible to separate the performance of an individual in scoring a goal from the contribution of the rest of the team *in the most general case*. If quantifying and assigning credit to players is so difficult, does it even make sense to try to assign credit to nodes in a complex system, with many pieces that are interacting in subtle ways?

Answer (score 1):

If you can do it well, it is useful.  If you can accurately identify which move was to blame for bad outcomes -- or which one is to credit for good outcomes -- that is useful in helping you learn to make better moves.  I'll let you decide whether that's enough for it to make sense to speak of it as a problem to be solved. I'm not very knowledgeable about philosophy, so I don't know whether that qualifies.

Comment: I like your pragmatic answer. I tend to look at things in an idealized way, so this is a different perspective for me.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what the system is used for. I mean, soccer (football) has a strict set of laws and limited number of moves whereas systems with limited laws and a high number of moves credit becomes more important. Like for example, with StackExchange: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17831/whats-the-incentive-to-answer-questions

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by soccer having a limited number of moves. What's a move? If it's just a physical relocation of a player, then there are infinitely many possibilities (or an unimaginably large finite number if you take space to be quantized).